# javascript array push error in Safari Browser

Tags: javascript, safari

I got this error

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '}'. Expected a ':' following the property name 'value'.
(anonymous function)
```

when doing this :

```
var datas1 = [];
angular.forEach(data.data, function(value, key) {
            if(value.comfi_type_id == "1" || value.comfi_type_id == "3" || value.comfi_type_id == "4")
                datas1.push({value})
        })
        $timeout(function() {
            $scope.items = {'data':{'data1':datas1}};
          }, 1000);
```

The code run fine on Chrome, but only Safari appeared to be error. Can anyone enlighten me, what is wrong?

`Question Update`

After I doing this

```
datas1.push({value:value})
```

It is now run fine in Safari browser. But now when I tried on ios device (this is ionic app) the code is not functioning. No data is push inside `datas1`

I thought when everything work on Safari, also work on ios device ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Safari probably doesn't support the short object notation ({ value }). You have to specify the key and the value:

```
datas1.push({ value: value });
```

Comment: That's great, it is working now. Will mark as answer later :)

Comment: @MiG I'd like to add that short object notation is an ES6 feature, so probably best to avoid using it directly if you plan to support multiple browsers.

Comment: Hi, I have update my question. The last fix run fine on Safari, but not yet in ios device. Why's that?

Comment: It should work. Is the condition fulfilled? Maybe there are some different data.

Comment: ahh yeah...I do platform remove ios then re-added, clean and rebuild on xcode. Everything is working fine now. Maybe I too panic :P ..thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

I also had this issue. It was because, I was using

```
var newObj = [];
for (var k in dataArray) {
    newObj.push(datArr[k]);
}
```

This 'for-loop' creates issue only in Safari and it adds additionally a function object to the array and array length always actual length + 1.

I fixed by replacing this for loop with the below format,

```
var newObj = [];
for (var k = 0 ; k < dataArray.length; k++) {
    newObj.push(datArr[k]);
}
```